# Difference between .pre and a simple query mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose

What are the differences between:

```
const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
    const deleteComments = await Comment.deleteMany({ post: req.params.postId });
    const deletedPost = await Post.findOneAndDelete({
      $and: [{ _id: req.params.postId }, { user: req.user }],
    });
    res.json(deletedPost);
};
```

and

```
const deletePost = async (req, res) => {
    const deletedPost = await Post.findOneAndDelete({
      $and: [{ _id: req.params.postId }, { user: req.user }],
    });
    res.json(deletedPost);
};
```

+the post model

```
postSchema.pre("findOneAndDelete", async function () 
    const deleteAssociatedComments = await Comment.deleteMany({ post: postId });
 );
```

Why would i want to use .pre inside the model instead of just running the query in the deletePost function?

Answer (score 0):

Pre and Post are known as hooks, it's similar to the concept of middlewares in express, those are functions which are executed during the execution of a function.

Pre is executed before the method is called and Post is executed after method has finished.

If you are going to decorate an existing method with more functionality you should use pre and post, If you are creating a custom query, you should use the query syntax, also if you want to run cascade operations after an operation is successful those hooks can work.